# converting array to json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array in java script .. something like:
`var myarray = ['a','b',c'];` and `var item = 'Name';`
and I want to convert that to something like

```
{
 a:{
    b:{
       c:{
          item:'Name'     
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That's an object, not JSON.

Comment: @Barmar is right. But in case you `do` need a JSON string and simply didn't format the question correctly, just take one of the answers below, and do `JSON.stringify( result )` to get a JSON representation of that object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = myarray.reverse().reduce(function (value, key) {
    var result = {};
    result[key] = value;
    return result;
}, { item : item });
```

In other words, you're packing the result layer by layer into new objects, using your keys from the array.

Comment: That probably should be `reverse().reduce( ... )`

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {};
var curobj = obj;
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    var newObj = {};
    newObj[myarray[i]] = newObj;
    curObj = newObj;
}
curObj.item = item;
```

The result you want will be in the `obj` object.