# Convert an array to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
array:2 [
    "test1_test2_test3" => "result"
    "category_slug" => "the_slug"
]
```

What I need to do is convert it to a multidimensional array that would look something like this:

```
array:2 [
    "test1" => [
        "test2" => [
            "test3" => "result"
        ]
    ]
    "category" => [
        "slug" => "the_slug"
    ]
]
```

I know that I can `explode` on the key to get an array but am unsure of how to then go from this to end up with the final result.

**EDIT** The array looks like that initially because it's being pulled from request parameters: `http://url.com?test1.test2.test3=result&category.slug=the_slug` and Laravel auto converts it to an array.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create the array in the way you later want to use it?

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37356543/3392762

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP explode string key into multidimensional array with values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37356391/php-explode-string-key-into-multidimensional-array-with-values)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach (array_reverse(explode('_', $key)) as $key_part) {
        $value = [$key_part => $value];
    }
    $result += $value;
}
```

If you need to handle several keys with the same parts (such as `test1_test2_test3` and `test1_test2_test4`), replace the last line with:

`$result = array_merge_recursive($result, $value);`

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to reverse the array, then loop through the keys and nest them.

The code below should do the trick.

```
$array = [
    "test1_test2_test3" => "result",
    "category_slug" => "the_slug"
];

$array = array_map(function ($key, $value) {
    $keys = array_reverse(explode('_', $key));
    while($key = array_shift($keys)) {
        $value = [$key => $value];
    }

    return $value;
}, array_keys($array), $array);

$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
var_dump($array);

/**
array(2) {
    ["test1"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["test2"]=>
        array(1) {
            ["test3"]=>
            string(6) "result"
        }
    }
    ["category"]=>
    array(1) {
        ["slug"]=>
        string(8) "the_slug"
    }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go:

```
$arr = array("test1_test2_test3" => "result", "category_slug" => "the_slug");
$res = array();

foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {

        $t = explode("_", $k);
        $new_arr = array();
        $tmp = $v; 
        for($i=count($t)-1; $i > 0; $i--) {
                $new_arr[$t[$i]] = $tmp;
                $tmp = $new_arr;
                $new_arr = array();
        }

        $res[$t[0]] = $tmp;

}

print_r($res);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [test1] => Array
        (
            [test2] => Array
                (
                    [test3] => result
                )

        )

    [category] => Array
        (
            [slug] => the_slug
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the Laravel documentation I found a helper `array_set`, which means in order to change the key to a multidimensional array I can change the key to use dot notation with `str_replace` and then use the helper to convert it over:

```
$array = [
    "test1_test2_test3" => "result"
    "category_slug" => "the_slug"
]

$new_array = []

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $key = str_replace('_', '.', $key);
    array_set($new_array, $key, $value);
}
```

Result:

```
array:2 [
    "test1" => [
        "test2" => [
            "test3" => "result"
        ]
    ]
    "category" => [
        "slug" => "the_slug"
    ]
]
```