# Assign an array value to another array called dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array like this

```
pages['name'] = "Home";
pages['childs'][0]['name'] = "Sub page 1";
pages['childs'][1]['name'] = "Sub page 2";
pages['childs'][2]['name'] = "Sub page 3";
pages['childs'][2]['childs'][0]['name'] = "Sub sub page 1";
```

My problem is that I need to change portions of the array for example.

```
pages['childs'][0] = otherarray;
// or
pages['childs'][2]['childs'][0] = otherarray;
```

Obviously if otherarray was a string I can easily do something like

```
eval('pages' + where + ' = "' + stringvalue + '"');
```

But I've an array as value so I can't do

```
eval('pages' + where + ' = "' + otherarray + '"');
```

because the code executed will be

```
pages['childs'][0] = [object object];
```

What's the solution? Thanks

Comment: What's the question?  `pages['childs'][0] = [object object];` is valid if you just alert it out... it just means that `pages['childs'][0]` contains an object.

Comment: @JohnGreen I think what he has is a variable `where = "['childs'][0]"` and he wants to use that to determine what to assign.

Comment: In pseudo code I've to do something like this.

eval('pages' + where) = otherarray;

Comment: You need to write a parser for `where`. Then you can iterate down the object levels with those keys, and finally assign `otherarray`.

Comment: @Barmar - Then the first issue is that we're attempting to use `eval`.  : )

Comment: If you can convert `where` into an array of property values, you can use my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550129/converting-array-to-json-object/24550236#24550236

Comment: What do you think about this solution? 

eval("pages" + where + " = JSON.parse('" + JSON.stringify(otherarray) + "')");

Answer (score 0):

Rather than screw around with eval and stringifying things, you should just build an accessor.  Many would agree that using eval like this is just bad practice in every way.  I don't know if combining it with stringify makes it worse, but it certainly feels dirty.

Here's a basic, fairly stupid accessor, but it should give you the idea.

```
// Arguments:  array to modify; new value; series of nested array keys.
function modifyArray(base, value){
   var refObj = base;
   for (var ii=2, max=arguments.length; ii < max; ii++){
       if (!refObj) {
          return false;  // we supplied an invalid key.
       }
       if (ii == max-1){
           refObj[arguments[ii]] = value;
           return true;
       }
       refObj = refObj[arguments[ii]];
   }
   return false; // probably forgot to include keys.
}

modifyArray(pages, otherarray, 'childs', 2, 'childs', 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ts78brg/

Comment: This is not a solution. I need even a parse for the var where.

Comment: I don't know where 'where' comes from.  At the end of the day, its your code, you can build it and maintain it however you want -- but from my 20 years of code-writing, I can almost guarantee you that your eval/stringify solution will come back and bite you badly at some point.

Answer (score -1):

For me this solution works

```
eval("pages" + where + " = JSON.parse('" + JSON.stringify(otherarray) + "')");
```

It sounds more like a workaround then a solution but it works and for me it's enough.